# Adding image with HTML

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm working on an Outlook script for forwarding emails with a specific template. I'm having trouble adding a logo where `<img scr=` starts.

```
Public Sub FW(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim olForward As Outlook.MailItem
Set olForward = olItem.Forward
Set olLogo = Outlook.Application

If InStr(olItem.Subject, "AW:") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "WG:") Or _
  InStr(olItem.Subject, "Re:") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "FW:") Or _
  InStr(olItem.Subject, "Fwd:") Then 

    Stop

ElseIf InStr(olItem.Subject, "CH1") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "CH3") Then

    Const Path = "T:\TEMP\"
    Const Logo = "image001.jpg"

    With olForward & olLogo
        .Attachments.Add Path & Logo
        .Subject = olItem.Subject
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "<span style=color:#1F497D;font-size:11pt;font-family:calibri;>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "<span style=color:#1F497D;font-size:9pt;font-family:arial;><b>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ</b><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR>" & _
                    "<html><img scr=cid:" & Replace(Logo, " ", "%20") & "height=55 width=170></html><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ"
        .Display
        .To = "" 
        .CC = "" 
        .Send
    End With

End If


'// Clean up
Set olItem = Nothing
Set olForward = Nothing
Set olLogo = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You missing quotation marks around the cid

Comment: How so? Been trying to add it and come out only with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, should look something like this.

```
Public Sub FW(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim olForward As Outlook.MailItem
Set olForward = olItem.Forward

If InStr(olItem.Subject, "AW:") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "WG:") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "Re:") Or _
InStr(olItem.Subject, "FW:") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "Fwd:") Then 

    Stop

ElseIf InStr(olItem.Subject, "CH1") Or InStr(olItem.Subject, "CH3") Then 

    With olForward
        .Attachments.Add "C:\TEMP\logo.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .Subject = olItem.Subject
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "<span style=color:#1F497D;font-size:11pt;font-family:calibri;>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ</span><BR><BR>" & _
                    "<span style=color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:arial;>" & _
                    "<b>TEXT TUTAJ</b><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:logo.jpg'" & "width='170' height='55'><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ</span>"
        .To = "" 
        .CC = "" 
        .Display
        .Send
    End With

End If


'// Clean up
Set olItem = Nothing
Set olForward = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: That is just single quotes though if you wanted double see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348575/3649914)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing quotes, to put them in the easiest way is to double up on the quotes to handle a quote.

example below

```
 .HTMLBody = "<span style=color:#1F497D;font-size:11pt;font-family:calibri;>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ</span><BR><BR>" & _
                    "<span style=color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:arial;>" & _
                    "<b>TEXT TUTAJ</b><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ<BR>" & _
                    "<img src=""cid:logo.jpg""" & "width=""170"" height=""55""><BR>" & _
                    "TEXT TUTAJ</span>"
```